# Extremely slow LEFT JOIN on specific table

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

I am having trouble finding out why my query is extremely slow; 60 seconds on a Dual Xeon L5630 with 48GB DDR3 running Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP7.0-FPM and MariaDB 10.0.27

```
SELECT v.video_id, v.user_id, v.title, v.slug, v.rating, v.rated_by,
                          v.duration, v.thumb, v.total_views, v.total_comments, v.add_time,
                          v.view_time, v.status, v.source_id, v.orientation, v.thumbs,
                          v.featured, v.flagged, 
                          u.username, 
                          s.name, 
                          f.reason,
                          GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS categories
                   FROM video AS v
                   LEFT JOIN video_flags AS f ON (f.video_id = v.video_id)
                   LEFT JOIN video_sources AS s ON (s.source_id = v.source_id)
                   LEFT JOIN user AS u ON (u.user_id = v.user_id)
                   LEFT JOIN video_category AS vc ON (vc.video_id = v.video_id)
                   LEFT JOIN video_categories AS c ON (c.category_id = vc.category_id) GROUP BY v.video_id ORDER BY v.video_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

I've pinpointed the problem to be in the **video_flags** table, because when I comment the f.reason field and the left join on video_flags, the query only takes 152ms. The video_flags table has an index on video_id and the field type is the same in both tables INT(11)

When I run explain select I get the following back:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                        | rows    | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                       | 1219933 | Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ALL    | video_id      | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                       |       1 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | s     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | adb_network.v.source_id    |       1 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | adb_network.v.user_id      |       1 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | vc    | ref    | video_id      | video_id | 4       | adb_network.v.video_id     |       2 | Using index                                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | adb_network.vc.category_id |       1 | Using where                                     |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't know what I'm missing here, first I thought it had to something with the video_flags table being empty, then I added a record and the query was quick (200ms) but now the problem is back and the query is taking forever to complete again.

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Update:** added the explain select without the f.reason column for @somnium:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | v     | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY  | 4       | NULL                       |    5 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref    | video_id      | video_id | 4       | adb_network.v.video_id     |    1 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | s     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | adb_network.v.source_id    |    1 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | adb_network.v.user_id      |    1 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | vc    | ref    | video_id      | video_id | 4       | adb_network.v.video_id     |    2 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | adb_network.vc.category_id |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+------+-------------+
```

---

**Solution**: As suggested by @somnium I tried adding a `FORCE INDEX` on the `video_id` column and that has brought the query time down from 60 seconds to 272ms - still not sure why it would lose the index during a join but problem is solved. Thanks

```
SELECT v.video_id, v.user_id, v.title, v.slug, v.rating, v.rated_by,
                              v.duration, v.thumb, v.total_views, v.total_comments, v.add_time,
                              v.view_time, v.status, v.source_id, v.orientation, v.thumbs,
                              v.featured, v.flagged, 
                              u.username, 
                              s.name, 
                              f.reason,
                              GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS categories
                       FROM video v
                       LEFT JOIN video_flags f FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (video_id) ON (f.video_id = v.video_id)
                       LEFT JOIN video_sources s ON (s.source_id = v.source_id) 
                       LEFT JOIN user u ON (u.user_id = v.user_id)
                       LEFT JOIN video_category vc ON (vc.video_id = v.video_id)
                       LEFT JOIN video_categories c ON (c.category_id = vc.category_id) GROUP BY v.video_id ORDER BY v.video_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You have 1219933 in your video table and you are joining it to several other tables. You don't have any filter on this table so all those rows are used in those multiple joins. 60 seconds sounds really good. But you can try adding an index on video_id if you don't have already

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The weird thing is my query does multiple joins, the problem only occurs when the f.reason column is included, if I comment that out, the query takes only 120ms with all the other joins still intact. There is an index on video_flags.video_id so that shouldn't be the problem either

Comment: And you realize that you should aggregate all columns in your SELECT that you don't group by? MySQL allows otherwise but it is bad practice.

Comment: Can you add an `explain select` without the f.reason column?

Comment: @somnium I've added the explain select without f.reason in the original post.

Comment: @juergend thanks for your comment, can you explain why this is needed and why it is considered bad practice? If I change the query to SELECT COUNT(v.video_id) for example the query time is doubled and I don't understand the benefit of using this?

Comment: Question: does u.username, s.name, c.name have indexes?

Comment: If you don't aggregate the other columns and there are multiple records for a unique video then MySQL takes any records. You don't know which one. And other DB engines and even MySQL in STRICT MODE throws an error for that query.

Comment: @somnium u.username and s.name have indexes, c.name doesn't have an index.

Comment: Is the output 'correct' if you change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`?

Comment: @RickJames `JOIN` defaults to `INNER JOIN` so it would not return any results. The problem was that it somehow loses the index on the `video_id` column, when using `FORCE INDEX` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accidentally causing a full table scan over a large table `videos`. A list of potential issues can be found [at the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html).

### Potential problems

#### Missing keys

Looking at your explain without f.reason, the optimizer will ignore the `video_flags` table. This allows MySQL/MariaDB to fully utilize all indices.

When adding `f.reason`, MySQL now needs to match `v.video_id = f.video_id`. As `video_flags` has one row, MySQL will attempt to retrieve `v.video_id` for every entry in `video`. It looks like you don't have an index on `v.video_id`. Therefore MySQL will have to scan the full `videos` table from the disk/memory in order to obtain `video_id`. This results in 1219933 rows retrieve (compared to 5 in the `explain select` without `video_flags`).

#### Low cardinality

Another potential issue is low cardinality, but I am not really sure what exactly causes the optimizer screw this up.

From the MySQL documentation:

> You are using a key with low cardinality (many rows match the key value) through 
>   another column. In this case, MySQL assumes that by using the key it probably 
>   will do many key lookups and that a table scan would be faster.

My understanding is that due to the very low cardinality (1-2 values) in `video_flags` it might cause MySQL to lookup the full table on `videos` due to the Left Join (you will always need ALL values from the left side). At this point it decides that full table scans are better. This does not happen in the other cases where you are using `video_id` because the cardinality is higher. You can force the usage of the index using the `FORCE INDEX` syntax.

### Potential solution

Try adding an index on `v.video_id` in order to speed up the lookups. Carefully check both `explain selects` to find which indices are suddenly not used. 
Note `NULL` for `possible_keys` for table `v` in your slow select.

Try using `FORCE INDEX`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `video_id` is the primary key in the `video` table, so `v.video_id` has an index. Looking at the first `explain select` it says NULL on the key column for both `video` and `video_flags` tables. It seems like the primary key is not being used somehow?

Comment: I am looking through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html. Maybe `FORCE INDEX` can help you.

Comment: Thank you @somnium adding `FORCE INDEX` seems to have fixed the problem. I'll update the original post with the final query. Not sure why it loses the index but your suggestion saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  See if this works better.  (It seems that there is no need to go through all that JOINing or GROUPing to get the 10 video_ids you desire.)

```
SELECT ...  -- as before
    FROM (
        SELECT video_id
            FROM video
            ORDER BY video_id DESC
            LIMIT 10 ) AS v1
    JOIN video AS v USING (video_id)
    LEFT JOIN ...  -- as before
    ...
    ORDER BY video_id DESC;  -- no GROUP BY or LIMIT here
```

Plan B:  Turn LEFT JOINs into subqueries

```
s.name,
LEFT JOIN video_sources AS s ON (s.source_id = v.source_id)
```

-->

```
( SELECT name FROM video_sources WHERE source_id = v.source_id ) AS name,
```

Ditto for any other single-line values and their left-joins.